# Checking for duplicates in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to check for duplicates in the database, but somehow it is not working.
In my form the user can select multiple checkboxes and after they sent it, their userID comes with it thanks to a hidden field. I want to check if a combination of their UserID and ANY of the checkboxes is already present in the database.

I have the following code: (database connection has been made already of course.

```
<?php
$UserID = $_POST['UserID'];
$Datum = $_POST['Datum'];

$check = mysql_query("SELECT `UserID`, `Datum` FROM `Werkdagen` WHERE `userID`='$UserID' AND `Datum`='$Datum' LIMIT 1");

if (mysql_num_rows($check)>0)
{
     $error = "<span class='error'>Je staat hebt je al opgegeven voor één van deze werkdagen!</span>";
} else {
     foreach ($_POST['Datum'] as $date){
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Werkdagen` (`UserID`, `Datum`) VALUES ('$UserID', '$date')");         
            $success = "<span class='success'>Je werkdagen zijn opgeslagen!</span>";}
            }
?>
```

What did I do wrong here?

Litte side note: I know I should be using prepared statements and all, but this is fine for the time being.

Comment: what makes you belive, you are doing somthing wrong?

Comment: $Datum returns data as array ?

Comment: Even though there are duplicates it gets inserted anyway. $Datum returns as an array, yes.

Comment: If your query does work and it does find a duplicate, then try adding an `exit;` after your `$error...` inside your conditional statement @user3158893 or use `die("<span class='error'>Je staat...");`

Comment: I think the problem is in AND `Datum`='$Datum'. First, check that they are ints. Apply intval to $UserID  and $Datum. For me, the main problem is that your query shows null.

Comment: Yes your $Datum is in array and you are using that in query resulting no data every time.

Comment: If you use array, then you need to have next query:
"SELECT `UserID`, `Datum` FROM `Werkdagen` WHERE `userID`='$UserID' AND (`Datum`='$Datum[1]' OR `Datum`='$Datum[2]' .... )LIMIT 1" or "SELECT `UserID`, `Datum` FROM `Werkdagen` WHERE `userID`='$UserID' AND `Datum` IN ('$Datum[1]','$Datum[2]' .... )

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to check if it has already been entered, it's pointless to actually retrieve the data.

```
SELECT COUNT(UserID) counted
FROM   Werkdagen
WHERE  userID =  $user_id 
AND    Datum  = '$datum'
```

Just make sure you save the dates as timestamp or datetime. When you fetch this result, you can check "counted" in your array to see if there is a match (note**: cast to int before checking or you will always get true in your if-statement).

Oh and please make sure you escape all your data (that's why prepared statements are nice!). You don't want employees deleting or truncating your data ;)

** Some more information regarding types:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

If you cast "1" or "0" to a bool directly, both will end up being "true", as the string is filled. If you cast them to an int first, it will cast them to 1 and 0 respectively. 1 == true and 0 == false where as "1" == true and "0" == true.

Comment: As a PHP newbie, how can I apply this exactly?

Comment: You put this in your query and then you fetch the rows with mysql_fetch_assoc, dump the result and you will see what I mean. Oh and to the one downvoting my good answer please tell me why you disagree cause this is the way you count rows using mysql. If you can't deal with an answer you don't like, just get out -.-"

Answer (score 0):

### What's wrong with my code?

You are setting a **LIMIT** of 1 on `$check`, so it will only check against one.

Example:  I have `food` and `cheese` in my table, and I'm checking for `cheese`, but the limit is **1.**  I will only be checking against `food` for `cheese` in this case.

### How do I fix it?

Change:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT `UserID`, `Datum` FROM `Werkdagen` 
WHERE `userID`='$UserID' AND `Datum`='$Datum' LIMIT 1");
```

to:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT `UserID`, `Datum` 
FROM `Werkdagen` WHERE `userID`='$UserID' AND `Datum`='$Datum'");
```

#### That's out of the way!  Great, but it's still posting duplicates

I doubt it will come to this, but if it is, make sure that **ALL** fields are matched (ex: date might not be the same (Datum means date)).

Comment: Thank you for your input, maybe the LIMIT 1 was part of the problem, but it doesn't solve it all the way. My guess is the problem being the checkboxes return as an array.

Answer (score 0):

May be this may help

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT `UserID`, `Datum` FROM `Werkdagen` WHERE `userID`='$UserID' AND `Datum` IN ('".implode(",",$Datum )."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $Datum is array and if you do echo $Datum, you see nothing, because you need to access each element. 
What I suppose is to use next:

```
$begin_query = "SELECT `UserID`, `Datum` FROM `Werkdagen` WHERE `userID`='$UserID' AND `Datum` IN (";

foreach ( $Datum as $key=>$value)
{
$begin_query =$begin_query."'".$key."'"; //or $value, I do not know how they are stored
}
$begin_query = $begin_query.") LIMIT 1";
$check = mysql_query($begin_query);
```

Comment: However, it is interested to see such query in prepared statements. There was some trick to make it work, as you do not know number of parameters to bind. (You cannot put array there - just to let you know)